# How do I add the result of a SELECT as a new column in an existing table?

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table, select-into

In SQL (whichever variant you like, say MySQL or MonetDB) it's very intuitive and straightforward to do:

```
CREATE TABLE t2 AS SELECT c1 FROM t1;
```

and get the selection result as a new column in a new table. But what if you want the result as a new column in the *same* table (table `t1`)? Let's assume `c1` is of type `INT` and may be null. We would need to write:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD c2 INT;
UPDATE TABLE t1 SET c2 = c1;
```

and that's the easy version, since if it's a non-null column we would need to initialize the new column with some value; and if the data comes from multiple tables I'd need some kind of inner query in the `UPDATE` (if it would be at all possible).

Can I select-into-a-column with a single command somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You use `join`:

```
UPDATE t1 JOIN
       t2
        ON t2.? = t1.?
   SET t1.c2 = t2.c1;
```

The `?` is a placeholder for the column used to identity which row in `t2` should update which row in `t1`.

Comment: But I don't have a `t2`. I only have `t1`. I want to avoid creating `t2`.